# HTTP2_SESSION_CLOSE

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, http2

I have a project written in react , it is served by nginx http/2 .

Since a week after updating chrome from 117 to 118 sometimes requests do not arrive.
The problem occurs only on windows and only on chrome.
If I use netstat I see seven tcp4 connections with status TIME_WAIT.

It looks like a bug related to the filled stream id pool in http2.

```
t=10512 [st=  0] +HTTP2_SESSION  [dt=828]
                  --> host = "my-project.com:443"
                  --> proxy = "DIRECT"
t=10512 [st=  0]    HTTP2_SESSION_INITIALIZED
                    --> protocol = "h2"
                    --> source_dependency = 71607 (SOCKET)
t=10512 [st=  0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS
                    --> settings = [
                          "[id:1 (SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE) value:65536]",
                          "[id:2 (SETTINGS_ENABLE_PUSH) value:0]",
                          "[id:4 (SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE) value:6291456]",
                          "[id:6 (SETTINGS_MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE) value:262144]"
                        ]
t=10512 [st=  0]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 15663105
                    --> window_size = 15728640
t=10512 [st=  0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_WINDOW_UPDATE
                    --> delta = 15663105
                    --> stream_id = 0
t=10512 [st=  0]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_HEADERS
                    --> exclusive = true
                    --> fin = true
                    --> has_priority = true
                    --> :method: GET
                        :authority: my-project.com
                        :scheme: https
                        :path: /manifest.json
                        sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"
                        sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
                        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
                        sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
                        accept: */*
                        sec-fetch-site: same-origin
                        sec-fetch-mode: cors
                        sec-fetch-dest: manifest
                        referer: https://my-project.com/dashboard
                        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                        accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
                    --> parent_stream_id = 0
                    --> source_dependency = 71603 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
                    --> stream_id = 1
                    --> weight = 183
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_SEND_SETTINGS_ACK
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTING
                    --> id = "3 (SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS)"
                    --> value = 128
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_STREAMS_SEND_WINDOW_SIZE
                    --> delta_window_size = 1
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTING
                    --> id = "4 (SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE)"
                    --> value = 65536
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTING
                    --> id = "5 (SETTINGS_MAX_FRAME_SIZE)"
                    --> value = 16777215
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_WINDOW_UPDATE
                    --> delta = 2147418112
                    --> stream_id = 0
t=10661 [st=149]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_SEND_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 2147418112
                    --> window_size = 2147483647
t=10663 [st=151]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_SETTINGS_ACK
t=10663 [st=151]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                    --> fin = false
                    --> :status: 200
                        server: nginx/1.14.1
                        date: Tue, 17 Oct 2023 13:11:24 GMT
                        content-type: application/json
                        last-modified: Sat, 26 Oct 1985 08:15:00 GMT
                        etag: W/"1dc09d84-1ec"
                        cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
                        content-encoding: gzip
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=10666 [st=154]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = false
                    --> size = 259
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=10666 [st=154]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = -259
                    --> window_size = 15728381
t=10666 [st=154]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                    --> fin = true
                    --> size = 0
                    --> stream_id = 1
t=10666 [st=154]    HTTP2_SESSION_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                    --> delta = 259
                    --> window_size = 15728640
t=11339 [st=827]    HTTP2_SESSION_CLOSE
                    --> description = "Low memory"
                    --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=11340 [st=828]    HTTP2_SESSION_POOL_REMOVE_SESSION
t=11340 [st=828] -HTTP2_SESSION
```

How to fix this error? Can vpn be the cause of such errors?